# unable to connect to mysql while install edx configuration with ansible

Tags: mysql, ansible, edx

I already want to install `edx-configuarion` platform in my ubuntu server.I read [this wiki on github](https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/edX-Ubuntu-12.04-Installation) but when I run this command :

```
$ sudo ansible-playbook -c local ./edx_sandbox.yml -i "localhost,"
```

I get this error:

```
TASK: [edxlocal | create a database for edxapp] ******************************* 
failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true, "item": ""}
msg: unable to connect, check login_user and login_password are correct, or alternatively check ~/.my.cnf contains credentials

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

I changed my `root` user password to `''` but still the same problem.I also change the `EDXAPP_MYSQL_USER` to `root` and `EDXAPP_MYSQL_PASSWORD` to another password in `playbooks/roles/edxapp/defaults/main.yml` but still same problem :(

Comment: what don't you just put the passw in the my.cnf file !

Comment: I put this but same problem :(

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: no, I don't found any solution for this yet

Answer (score 2):

The method you were using suppose to work in a freshly installed Ubuntu server. It also meant that you'd already installed mysql in your server. So, to fix this issue, create this file **/root/.my.cnf** with the following content:

```
[client]
user=root
password=<your root pass>

[mysql]
user=root
password=<your root pass>

[mysqldump]
user=root
password=<your root pass>

[mysqldiff]
user=root
password=<your root pass>
```

Run the command again, It should work.

Comment: This is the correct answer. https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/Re-install-Open-edX-in-Ubuntu-12.04 and your password should be a string. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19913912/1154847

Comment: It's been a while since when I wrote that wiki page. I'm not sure if it's still correct in the newer releases of Open edX, but you can try.

Comment: Worked for me when installing Ironwood release, I was using one of the passwords generated in my_passwords.conf, but the real password to use was the password of the root user. Thanks @TrinhNguyen